# Replica set with 2 members, 1 hidden, yet primary sometimes becomes secondary

Tags: replication, mongodb

I have a replica set containing only two members:

```
test:PRIMARY> rs.config()
{
        "_id" : "test",
        "version" : 8,
        "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "localhost:50000",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "host" : "localhost:50002",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : true,
                        "priority" : 0,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                }
        ],
        "settings" : {
                "chainingAllowed" : true,
                "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
                "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
                "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
                "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : 2000,
                "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000,
                "getLastErrorModes" : {

                },
                "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
                        "w" : 1,
                        "wtimeout" : 0
                },
                "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("591de3c57f979533a0e4defa")
        }
}
test:PRIMARY>
```

Maybe you'll get triggered by the second member being on `localhost:50002`, that is because that port is a ssh tunnel to another machine, it is irrelevant in this context (see [MongoDB replica set over ssh tunnels](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/173911/mongodb-replica-set-over-ssh-tunnels))

The issue is when `localhost:50002` gets rebooted, sometimes the primary on `localhost:50000`, the "main machine" that is supposed to be the primary, steps down to secondary. Update: Turns out it does this always after the secondary has been down for some time (seconds to minutes).

This should not happen, since `localhost:50002` is `hidden:true` with a `priority:0`, and `localhost:50000` is still the only one which could get elected (should an election even be taking place).

The clients cease to be able to read/write to the database (because it's a secondary).

Both servers are v3.6.7.

The log shows the following entries (grepped to "repl")

```
2018-09-13T23:34:15.886+0200 I REPL     [replexec-149] Member localhost:50002 is now in state RS_DOWN
2018-09-13T23:34:15.886+0200 I REPL     [replexec-149] can't see a majority of the set, relinquishing primary
2018-09-13T23:34:15.886+0200 I REPL     [replexec-149] Stepping down from primary in response to heartbeat
2018-09-13T23:34:15.886+0200 I REPL     [replexec-149] transition to SECONDARY from PRIMARY
2018-09-13T23:34:15.886+0200 I NETWORK  [replexec-149] Skip closing connection for connection # 12889
2018-09-13T23:34:15.886+0200 I NETWORK  [replexec-149] Skip closing connection for connection # 12858
2018-09-13T23:34:15.886+0200 I NETWORK  [replexec-149] Skip closing connection for connection # 12857
2018-09-13T23:34:15.887+0200 I NETWORK  [replexec-149] Skip closing connection for connection # 11417

2018-09-13T23:34:16.779+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Ending connection to host localhost:50002 due to bad connection status; 0 connections to that host remain open
2018-09-13T23:34:16.780+0200 I REPL_HB  [replexec-150] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 1509228) to localhost:50002, response status: NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out

2018-09-13T23:34:17.280+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to localhost:50002

2018-09-13T23:34:26.503+0200 I REPL     [replexec-150] Not starting an election, since we are not electable due to: Not standing for election because I cannot see a majority (mask 0x1)
2018-09-13T23:34:27.280+0200 I REPL_HB  [replexec-149] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 1509230) to localhost:50002, response status: NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit: Couldn't get a connection within the time limit
2018-09-13T23:34:36.771+0200 I REPL     [replexec-149] Not starting an election, since we are not electable due to: Not standing for election because I cannot see a majority (mask 0x1)
2018-09-13T23:34:37.280+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to localhost:50002 - NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out
2018-09-13T23:34:37.280+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to localhost:50002
2018-09-13T23:34:37.780+0200 I REPL_HB  [replexec-150] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 1509232) to localhost:50002, response status: NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit: Couldn't get a connection within the time limit

2018-09-13T23:34:47.307+0200 I REPL     [replexec-150] Not starting an election, since we are not electable due to: Not standing for election because I cannot see a majority (mask 0x1)
2018-09-13T23:34:48.280+0200 I REPL_HB  [replexec-150] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 1509234) to localhost:50002, response status: NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit: Couldn't get a connection within the time limit

2018-09-13T23:34:52.353+0200 I NETWORK  [conn12897] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:36478 conn12897: { driver: { name: "NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication", version: "3.6.7" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Ubuntu", architecture: "x86_64", version: "16.04" } }

2018-09-13T23:34:57.280+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to localhost:50002 - NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out
2018-09-13T23:34:57.280+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to localhost:50002
2018-09-13T23:34:58.012+0200 I REPL     [replexec-150] Not starting an election, since we are not electable due to: Not standing for election because I cannot see a majority (mask 0x1)
2018-09-13T23:34:58.780+0200 I REPL_HB  [replexec-150] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 1509235) to localhost:50002, response status: NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit: Couldn't get a connection within the time limit
2018-09-13T23:35:06.309+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to localhost:50002 - HostUnreachable: Connection reset by peer
2018-09-13T23:35:06.309+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Dropping all pooled connections to localhost:50002 due to failed operation on a connection
2018-09-13T23:35:06.309+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to close stream: Transport endpoint is not connected
2018-09-13T23:35:06.309+0200 I REPL_HB  [replexec-150] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 1509237) to localhost:50002, response status: HostUnreachable: Connection reset by peer

...

2018-09-13T23:35:09.322+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to localhost:50002
2018-09-13T23:35:09.322+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to localhost:50002 - HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2018-09-13T23:35:09.322+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Dropping all pooled connections to localhost:50002 due to failed operation on a connection
2018-09-13T23:35:09.322+0200 I REPL_HB  [replexec-151] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 1509276) to localhost:50002, response status: HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2018-09-13T23:35:09.355+0200 I REPL     [replexec-150] Not starting an election, since we are not electable due to: Not standing for election because I cannot see a majority (mask 0x1)
2018-09-13T23:35:09.823+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Connecting to localhost:50002
2018-09-13T23:35:09.823+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Failed to connect to localhost:50002 - HostUnreachable: Connection refused
2018-09-13T23:35:09.823+0200 I ASIO     [NetworkInterfaceASIO-Replication-0] Dropping all pooled connections to localhost:50002 due to failed operation on a connection
2018-09-13T23:35:09.823+0200 I REPL_HB  [replexec-150] Error in heartbeat (requestId: 1509278) to localhost:50002, response status: HostUnreachable: Connection refused
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB server are you using? Do secondary & primary have identical versions (if not, what versions are being used)? There should be some messages in the `mongod` log for your primary around the time it changes role to a secondary: try searching for log lines containing `REPL`.

Comment: @Stennie I added the version and the logs, also it turns out that this happens always when the secondary goes missing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the configuration of the secondary:

```
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "host" : "localhost:50002",
                    "arbiterOnly" : false,
                    "buildIndexes" : true,
                    "hidden" : true,
                    "priority" : 0,
                    "tags" : {

                    },
                    "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                    "votes" : 1
            }
```

`"votes": 1` would give it the ability to vote, but since it is down, it cannot vote, then the primary realizes that it is unable to perform an election (regardless of it being the only electable candidate with `priority:1` and `hidden:false`), it steps down.

Setting `"votes": 0` will avoid this problem.